# Connect nodes with line with tikz

Tags: circuitikz

Using both

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
```

I try to connect nodes with

```
\draw (p1) to(p2) to(p3);
\draw (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3);
```

But both ways give `lines with` empty space where the `nodes` are.
How do I make one continuous line?

Comment: Instead of `node(p1){}` something use `coordinate(p1)` in your document. `node`s produce these spaces since they have a nontrivial volume.

Comment: You can also use `\draw (p1.center) -- (p2.center) -- (p3.center);` Yet it is hard to say more since you do not show a complete example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is solved by comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to close the question, I wasn't aware that nodes take a space, so coordinate should be used to draw a continous line.

Thank you  Schrödinger's cat for that one.

Comment: The nodes don't take any space. TikZ is intelligently designed. A node is usually a text surrounded by a frame. The lines connecting two nodes are designed to go from edge to edge and not to enter the node (unless requested).

Answer (score 2):

A simple example with circuitikz only to give an idea of the syntax and which can be easily deciphered--please show your exact requirement through a drawing even if drawn by hand

[image]

```
\documentclass [tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (0, 0) to[sV] (0, 6)
        (0, 6) -- (7, 6)
        (7, 6) -- (7, 5)
        (7, 5) to[R] (5, 3)
        (5, 3) to[R] (7, 1)
        (7, 1) -- (7, 0)
        (7, 0) -- (0, 0)
        (7, 1) to[R] (9, 3)
        (9, 3) to[R] (7, 5)
        (5, 3) -- (7, 3)
        circle [radius = 10pt]node[circle,fill=white,minimum size=10pt]{N}
        (7, 3) -- (9, 3) 
        ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: was this helpful?

Comment: first comment on my questions was the answer, but it may come in handy in the future, thanks!